# pstoedit gives different result while converting eps to dxf using "dxf" and "dxf_14"

Tags: svg, dxf

I am using pstoedit as a part of a shell script to convert svg to dxf.

When I use `pstoedit -psarg '-dNOSAFER' -dt -f 'dxf: -mm' "${epsfile}" "${dxffile}"` in script, the result is like the picture below.

[image: dxf]

But when i use `pstoedit -psarg '-dNOSAFER' -dt -f 'dxf_14: -mm' "${epsfile}" "${dxffile}"` the result is like the picture below.

[image: dxf_14]

See the difference? `dxf` gives complete lines, but `dxf_14` gives small lines not connected. I read `pstohedit -help` and it mentions to use `dxf_14` because it's newer, but I can't if it's going to produce results like this.

I also see a bunch of options specific to `dxf_14`, but I'm not sure what to use. Can anyone guide me on what switches to use for `dxf_14` to get desired result, like the first picture above?

PS. I'm using Inkscape to create svg and then the script converts svg to eps using inkscape cli and the pstoedit is used to convert eps to dxf, if it helps.

PS2. pstoedit version is `pstoedit: version 3.74 / DLL interface 108 (built: Oct 31 2019 - release build - g++ 9.2.0 - 64-bit)`

Comment: Did you manage to solve the issue? I have the exact same problem!

Comment: @Andres Nah, sadly I'm still using `dxf`.